Android Native Jitsi SDK issue while using React-Native Bridging-Conflict with React_native
JitsiMeetSDK            com.frontm.onship                    E  JitsiMeetUncaughtExceptionHandler FATAL ERROR (Ask Gemini)
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: "App" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., stack:
@26:290
runApplication@129:1613
value@33:3866
@33:675
value@33:2510
value@33:646
value@-1
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                
                                                                                                com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: "App" has not been registered. This can happen if:
                                                                                                * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
                                                                                                * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., stack:
                                                                                                <unknown>@26:290
                                                                                                runApplication@129:1613
                                                                                                value@33:3866
                                                                                                <unknown>@33:675
                                                                                                value@33:2510
                                                                                                value@33:646
                                                                                                value@-1
                                                                                                
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

2024-12-06 14:19:32.107 26242-26242 OrientationModule       com.frontm.onship
I am trying to launch JitsiMeetView and getting this crash, This is due to my React-Naive bridging in my native side
